# Perl Catalyst encoding issue

Tags: perl, utf-8, catalyst

Well this is strange and hard to explain what's wrong but I'll try do my best.

For some reason values to template changes their encoding (I'm pretty sure they are).

Controller file (encoded in UTF-8):

```
print STDERR "ąęść";
$c->stash->{some_variable} = "ąęść"; # some unicode chars
```

Template file (encoded in UTF-8):

```
[% some_variable %]<br>
test: ąęść
```

As output in browser I'm getting:

```
ÄÄÅÄ
test: ąęść
```

Output on console (with UTF-8 encoding enabled):

```
ąęść
```

Comment: Do you have `use utf8;` in your controller file?

Comment: It looks like you don't have `ENCODING => 'utf-8'` in your TT config.

Comment: Configuration is fine. For some reason template file content is corrupted. When I remove everything from template file and place there only variable it works...

Comment: @J33nn Wait, so when your template contains `[% some_variable %]<br>
test: ąęść`, you get `ÄÄÅÄ
test: ąęść`, but when your template contains only `[% some_variable %]` and nothing else, you get `ąęść`? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I've found that if I have for example this char `ß` (even commented out `<!-- ß -->`) if totally mess up encoding.

Comment: I think you need to reduce the misbehaving application to a minimum that displays the same behaviour. It shouldn't be difficult. You may well find the problem yourself in the process, but you will then have something you can post here that others can work with,

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the good documentation provided by the Catalyst Wiki at [Using Unicode](http://wiki.catalystframework.org/wiki/tutorialsandhowtos/using_unicode.view) and also [Catalyst::View::TT](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::View::TT#Unicode-Catalyst-v5.90080). The [Perl Unicode Cookbook](http://www.perl.com/pub/2012/04/perlunicook-standard-preamble.html) may help you get a better understanding on Perl support of UTF-8, usually better than most other languages available today.

You may need to save your templates with the UTF-8 BOM mark using your editor, so your text editor does encode properly your template file when saving, or if not setting BOM, then at least define file encoding as UTF-8 every time you save it.

Answer (score 1):

There's been a ton of fixes to unicode support and UTF-8 in general with the most recent stable release of Catalyst (5.90084).  Catalyst now is UTF-8 by default, but of course there's always some hard edges.  You should review the most recent docs on the subject to see what is going wrong.

If you template contains multibyte character than you do indeed need to set the BOM or review the documentation for your template view of choice.